# Teamviewer works, ssh doesn't work

Tags: ssh, teamviewer

In my workspace, citrix nsg is applied. Given that they don't have a rpm of nsg client, I can't use it from my fedora.

As an alternative, they have provided me a desktop with teamviewer. Problem is, now I can use the desktop from my local machine using temaviewer,ssh fails to connect fk desktop's network.
I am  confused how is this possible?
If there is no ip, what teamviewer connected?

Comment: Relating read: https://superuser.com/q/661749/955970

Comment: Why do you say that there is no IP? There are many reasons for ssh to fail to connect. However, to be honest, I don't know how Teamviewer operates. Two more comments: (1) What do you mean by "the desktop's network" - you can't connect to the desktop, or to any machine in the desktop's network? (2) The word "fk" is an obvious typo. Please correct it; do you mean "to"?

Answer (score 1):

TeamViewer and SSH are very, very different things... TeamViewer has an app installed on the remote host.  That application is making an outbound connection to the TeamViewer servers.

When you connect to a remote computer using TeamViewer, your local TeamViewer client is reaching out to TeamViewer servers to find the remote client by ID#.  Once it finds the client, it makes a connection back down to the client through the ALREADY OPEN outbound connection that the application on the remote machine has established.

It's entirely possible to have TeamViewer running and accessible without having ever enabled SSH access to the server.

---

SSH is entirely different.  The SSHD daemon binds to the local server IP on port 22 (or a different one if you've specified that). It listens on that port for INCOMING connections (it doesn't establish an outbound session as TeamViewer does...). For incoming SSH sessions to work, you must have a properly set up network to allow it, you must have valid SSH keys, or user/password if you are doing it that way.

---

You didn't give any details to your setup, what version of Fedora? Are you trying to connect to the Fedora system, or from it to something else ("from my fedora" is ambiguous)?